# Jenkins as JobServer on Hadoop EdgeNode

Tags: hadoop, jenkins, mapr

I´m not sure that someone can help me but I´ll take a try.

I´m running Jenkins on an Openshift-Cluster to use it for Deployment and as a jobserver for running ETL-Jobs. These jobs are transferring data from flatfiles to databases and from db to db.

Now, I should expand the system to transfer data to a hadoop cluster using MapR.
What I would like to know is, how can I use a new Jenkins-Slave as a jobserver on an EdgeNode from the hadoop-cluster using MapR. Do I need the Jenkins on the EdgeNode or am I able to use MapR from my existing Jenkins-Jobserver?

Mabye, someone is able to help me or has some informations/links how to solve it.

Thx to all....

Answer (score 0):

"Use MapR" isn't quite clear to me because I just view it as Hadoop at the end of the day, but you can effectively make your Jenkins slave an "edge node" by installing only the Hadoop Java (maybe also MapR) client utilities plus any XML configuration files from the other edge nodes that define how to communicate with the cluster.

Then, Jenkins would be able to run `sh("hadoop jar app.jar")`, for example

If you're using Openshift, you might also try putting a Hadoop client inside a Docker image that could run in Jenkins, or anywhere else